# How can I use `InSampleSize` for pictures that I get from the camera intent? (Bitmap)

Tags: android, bitmap, large-files

I've got this piece of code but it works only when the user has to choose the picture from the gallery:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;                  
mPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
image.setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
```

So I have a bitmap file, `mPhoto`. It has an image in it.

I need to apply the options on that photo.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it like that:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 10;
  mPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri.getPath(), options);
```